# How to add gap between two buttons in JToolBar?

Tags: java, swing, layout, border-layout, jtoolbar

I need to add a simple gap/space/margin whatever to have space between these two buttons. Unfortunately I can't make it work. Could anyone give me some advice?

It's based on `BorderLayout`, the buttons are in a `JToolBar`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`JToolBar.addSeparator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html#addSeparator--) which:

> Appends a separator of default size to the end of the tool bar. The default size is determined by the current look and feel.

Or [`JToolBar.addSeparator(Dimension)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html#addSeparator-java.awt.Dimension-) which:

> Appends a separator of a specified size to the end of the tool bar.

Answer (score 5):

What layout is on the `JPanel` that contains those buttons? You could use a `BoxLayout` and add `Box.createHorizontalStrut()` to it.

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
buttonPanel.add(playButton);
buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(25));
buttonPanel.add(stopButton);
buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Comment: The layout must be BorderLayout

Comment: Why? Are you sure the layout of the main content pane isn't the one with the BorderLayout?

Comment: No, no, use BorderLayout for the main content pane, and use BoxLayout for each component that you add to the BorderLayout.  Using a BorderLayout within a BorderLayout is just odd.

Comment: Sorry, on JPanel is BorderLayout but these buttons are inside JToolBar

Comment: My advice is the same for a JToolBar. Try it out and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Note that you might set the layout of the tool-bar to `BoxLayout` .. I've used `FlowLayout` in a tool-bar to good effect. This is better than using a panel (added to the toolbar) with a layout for at least a few reasons. 1) The tool-bar might have a gradient paint behind it that the fixed color panel does not replicate (without `setOpaque(false)`). 2) An action can be added directly to a tool-bar, but not to a panel. 3) And of course, the toolbar will have its own, PLAF specific, separator (which is invisible on some PLAFs, and visible in others).